# NPM warning when installing gulp-sass: "cross-spawn-async@2.2.4..."

Tags: node.js, powershell, gulp-sass

When installing gulp-sass through PowerShell, I saw an NPM warning that I am trying to understand.

I typed `npm install gulp-sass` in PowerShell, and while it appears the installation was successful, I saw this warning in the beginning:

> npm WARN deprecated cross-spawn-async@2.2.4: cross-spawn no longer
>   requires a build toolchain, use it instead!

I am trying to understand what this warning means and what I should do about it. What is "it" that I should be using instead of "what"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that cross-spawn-async 2.2.4 is deprecated, and that gulp-sass is currently using that version. "It" is the [updated cross-spawn package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cross-spawn).

Comment: Since cross-spawn-async is used by gulp-sass, is there anything I can do about the warning, or is it something that the gulp-sass team would need to address?

Comment: Nope, but since it's a WARN, I wouldn't worry about it.